# How to stop IntelliJ from reformatting SQL code?

Tags: sql, intellij-idea, code-formatting, intellij-idea-2016

IntelliJ reformats my SQL code when I type a closing parentheses. How do I turn this off? For example, I'm write something like:

[image]

Now, when I type a ')' at the right margin, to close of that common table expression, it re-writes the code like this:

[image]

How do I turn this off? I know I can change some things in Preferences under Editor > Code Style > SQL. For example, I can tell it not to uppercase by keywords. But I want to tell it not to reformat my code when I type a ')'.  There is a checkbox to "disable formatting", but if I check that then I can't even reformat code even when I want to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `Editor` > `General` > `Smart keys` there is a checkbox `Reformat block on typing '}'`.

It seems like it also works for `)` in SQL.

The downside is that it is a single option for all languages, so it won't work if you want a different behaviour only for SQL.

Comment: In other languages it works well. In SQL it does a mess...